# Read data from external API every 10 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I need to read some data from external API every 10 seconds and save them to my database. I have tried doing it with cron job - gem **whenever**, but it doesn't allow time intervals smaller than 1 minute. What is the best way in Rails 4+ to run some background job every few seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`resque`](https://github.com/resque/resque) with [`resque-scheduler`](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) to run those background jobs.

For example, given this job:

```
class ReadDataFromApiJob
  def self.perform
    data = read_from_api
    save(data)
  end

  def read_from_api
    # ...
  end

  def save(data)
    # save to db
  end
end
```

You can create a scheduled job to run it every 10 seconds in a `config/resque_schedule.yml` file:

```
---
ReadDataFromApiJob:
  every:
    - 10s
  class: ReadDataFromApiJob
  queue: my_queue
  description: This job will read and save data from the api every 10 seconds
```